# Convert three values ​of list dropdowns to a string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three drop-down lists, day, month and year.

**First:** I want to put a conditional code that if all three is selected, something is done.

**Second:** I want to store the values ​​of all three in a string variable,

```
<select class="form-control custom-select"> // day
<option value="">days</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
```

```
<select class="form-control custom-select">// month
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
```

```
<select class="form-control custom-select">// years
<option value="">years</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
```

I want the inside of the variable to be stored as follows...

`var string = "1 January 2017"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would say when they are all three null, based on your code provided, but for the string part you can do.

```
var s = "";
$('.custom-select').change(function() {
  s = $('.custom-select').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get().join(" ");
  console.log(s);
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var s = "";
$('.custom-select').change(function() {
  s = $('.custom-select').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  var n = jQuery.inArray("", s) > -1;
  $('.button').toggle(!n)
  if (!n) {
    s = s.join(" ");
    console.log(s);
  }
}).first().trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control custom-select date">
  <option value="">days</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control custom-select month">
  <option value="">month</option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="February">February</option>
  <option value="March">March</option>
  <option value="April">April</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control custom-select year">
  <option value="">years</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
</select>


<button class="button">Show if selects have value.</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Now if I want to put a conditional code that they are all null?

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy As i said, how do you expect them to be null?

Comment: I want all three to be stored together in the database if one is not selected

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy again, How can 1 option in a select not be selected? with the current code you have provide, 1 option will always be selected.

Comment: I want all selectors selected to display a button

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy displaying a button if all "is" selected is not part of your original question, but again you have to address the problem, that with your current code, NONE of the select will be empty, and they will always be selected

Comment: I have an item inside each option whose value is null
`<option value = "">days</option>`

Comment: I edited original question

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy check the demo now